# kotlin passing function as argument got Type mismatch, Required: ()->Unit, Found: Unit

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-function-type

Having a function which takes function type for the callback

```
fun dataBtnClickHandler(callbackFunc: () -> Unit){

    // do something
    ......

    // call the callback function
    callbackFunc     
}
```

And there is a function defined as

```
private fun lunchStartActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, StartActivity::class.java)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putInt(FRAGMENT_PREFERENCE, fragmentPreference)
    intent.putExtras(bundle)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

in the click switch it call the `dataBtnClickHandler` and passing the `lunchStartActivity()`  for the callback.

But it gets error: `Type mismatch, Required: ()->Unit, Found: Unit`, what does the error mean?

```
when (clickedId) {
   R.id.data_btn -> dataBtnClickHandler(lunchStartActivity())  //<=== Error:  Type mismatch, Required: ()->Unit, Found: Unit
```

Comment: read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your method expects a function argument that returns unit.

```
callbackFunc: // Name with a type that is
    () // a 0 arg function
    -> Unit // that returns Unit (AKA void, or nothing)
```

If you pass the method call directly, you give the method an argument that consists of the return type. The way you originally did would pass Unit to the method.

To pass an actual method, and not just the return type from a call, as an argument, you use `::`:

```
dataBtnClickHandler(::launchStartActivity)
```

Alternatively `this::launchStartActivity` if it's in the current object/class, or replace `this` with a class name (or file name if it's a top-level function). Though :: works in most cases.

Remember; you're passing a method reference here, not the result of a method call, or a variable.

Comment: He also forgot to add the paretheses for `callbackFunc` in `dataBtnClickHandler`

Comment: @crgarridos I'm assuming that's a typo for the sake of an MCVE (code shortened and that was accidentally left out). But you're right, it is missing.

Comment: with callbackFunc only, there is no complain, and callbackFunc.invoke() works as well.  update, @crgarridos, you're right,  the compiler does not complain.

Comment: Something doesn't add up; the error says you have a `() -> Int`, but you're actually using `() -> Unit` in the MCVE? Is that a typo @lannyf? Either the error is wrong, or the MCVE is.

Comment: right, it is typo and pasted in a few places. should be Unit. Thanks!

Comment: It's not too big a deal though, the same still applies. Just nice to know so I can write the answer as correctly as possible :)